# Missing space after bash test bultin - legal syntax or undefined?

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I made a small mistake today when writing a bash script. The following code

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "${UNDEFINED_VAR}"]; then
   echo 'string not empty'
   echo "$UNDEFINED_VAR"
else
   echo 'string empty'
fi
```

returns `string not empty` and a blank line. If you look closely I'm missing a space before `]` in the upper code. What suprised me a bit was that bash happily runs my code without any `unexpected token` (or other) syntax errors. On a side note `[[` gives a proper syntax error in the upper case.

**My question:** Is that just undefined behavior since I'm not using legal syntax and bash is free to do anything, or is it some kind of very strange legal syntax giving a very unexpected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `UNDEFINED_VAR` being unset, the command

```
[ -n "${UNDEFINED_VAR}"]
```

will expand to

```
[ -n ]
```

This is well defined and will be true as the string `-n` is non-empty.

The default test that `[` will perform for a single argument (disregarding `]`) is to test for a non-empty string. The string `-n` is a non-empty string.

Comment: Thx, perfect answer. Also answers the second question as `if [[ -n ]]; then` seem not to be legal syntax due to the missing operand after `-n` (contrary to `[` behavior).